# Change SKU to be non-unique

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, sku, ce-1.9.2.4

I want to change SKU Unique value to NO. How to edit this?

Comment: are you telling you want to give same sku for multiple products ?

Answer (score 5):

Technically it's possible with an upgrade script that changes the properties of the "sku" attribute.

But **don't do that**, Magento relies on distinctly referencing a product by its SKU. I worked on a shop where they made the SKU "not required" and faced countless bugs because of that. And these were not obvious bugs, so you would have fun with this for a long time.

Rather, ask yourself *why* you would want to do that: What's your actual problem?

See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem